Internal server issue while generating the access token
I've already created a code using AUTH-URL
Now I tried to create a token by using that code facing the internal server(500) issue
but before one hour I got a successful response, I got an access token
now I'm facing the issue, I Don't know why... can anyone help with this
After that, i created another Wp-demo account that used that account's clientID & secret it is working...
how to fix that issue for my main account?


I'd double check your local server's logs in case there's an error there from the redirect_url, but if not you should ask wordpress.com support since the 500 is at their end.
